# Why isnt this simple c snippet working

Tags: c, file-io

I want to just create a small **encryption program**, i want to read characters from a file and just add the current value of i to the characters and store it in a new file.

> example : **abcd** should be stored as **aceg**

Here is the code snippet:

```
main()
{
   int i=0,c;
   char filename[30],o_filename[30];
   FILE *file,*outfile;
   printf("\nEnter filename:");
   scanf("%s",&filename);
   printf("\nEnter output filename : ");
   scanf("%s",&o_filename);
   if( ( (file = fopen(filename,"a"))==NULL) || ((outfile = fopen(o_filename,"a+"))==NULL))
   printf("\nERROR - Cannot proceed");
   else
   {
       c = 0;
       while(c!=-1)
       {
                   c = getc(file);
                   putc((c+i),outfile);
                   i++;
       }
       printf("\nEncryption Successful!\n");
    }
    getch();
}
```

What's the bug with the above program?

Comment: I do not see a definition of `filename` and `o_filename`, but you should not be taking a pointer to them in the call of `scanf`: `scanf("%s", filename);`

Comment: Sorry i wrote it wrong in a hurry, now i have updated it.

Comment: Shouldn't you open the input file for read (`fopen(filename,"r")`)?

Comment: Remove ampersands from `scanf`s: they are generally unnecessary with `%s`. You should also replace `%s` with `%29s`, because you allocated only 30 characters for your strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Th function `getc` returns an `int`, not a `char`. `EOF` cannot be represented in a `char`.

Change the type of `c` to `int` and test against `EOF` in the loop.

#### EDIT

To correct the off by one error spotted by marc you could try this idiom:

```
while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
```

Comment: @Ravitheja In what way is it not working ?

Comment: @Ravitheja yes dude, it is wrong.

Comment: I have qwerty in the input file and after i run this and see in the output file, there is just one alphabet, a y with 2 dots above

Comment: @Ravitheja. The use of char to store the result from getch absolutely is wrong as cnicutar points out. You should definitely correct this. If the program is still not working you have some additional error.

Comment: @hlovdal ok i changed it but still not working

Comment: `EOF cannot be represented in a char.` — in a few *rare* cases it can.

Comment: @MichałGórny Yes, but generally you can't count on it. So I just simplified to "can't".

Answer (score 1):

As cnicutar noted, getc returns an int, and so `c` should be declared `int c`.

First, as cnicutar noted, you'll want to compare `c` to `EOF`, i.e. `while (c != EOF)`. Also, when you loop through the file and hit the end, what will happen? At the last iteration, `c = getc(file)` will be `EOF` but you're still using it to `putc(EOF+i,outfile)`.

Try one of the following two methods to fix this:

```
    do {
        c = getc(file);
        putc(c+i, outfile);
        i++;
    } while (c != EOF);
```

or

```
    c = getc(file);
    while (c != EOF) {
        putc(c+i, outfile);
        i++;
        c = getc(file);
    }
```

EDIT

As cnicutar pointed out, the last snippet can be condensed using a common `getc` idiom as follows:

```
    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF) {
        putc(c+i, outfile);
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Documentation for some of the above points: getc - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/getc/, and EOF - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/EOF/

Comment: Ok finally it worked thankz both of you guys.